# Youtube Data API V3 - Uploading video through PHP code shows error

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been using following code since a year now but suddenly this errors started appearing.

I'm using PHP Code sample provided in following url

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video

ERROR:

```
 {
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "youtube.thumbnail",
            "reason": "videoNotFound",
            "message": "The video that you are trying to insert a thumbnail image for cannot be found. Check the value of the requests \u003ccode\u003evideoId\u003c/code\u003e parameter to ensure that it is correct.",
            "locationType": "parameter",
            "location": "videoId"
        }],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "The video that you are trying to insert a thumbnail image for cannot be found. Check the value of the requests \u003ccode\u003evideoId\u003c/code\u003e parameter to ensure that it is correct."
    }
}
```

I've print statement just before this error catching, and I could see the video ID. And I could see a wiered behavior on my video url.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KV-5aiMDLDg

No comment box, no suggested videos.

Anyone else facing this issue, is there an error/Bug reported recently from Youtube?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same problem.  Code has been running fine forever, and now is failing.  I added a 20 second delay after the video upload completes, before the thumbnail is set, and it seems to always work now.  So it acts like Youtube needs time to digest the video.  Would love to hear a better solution though.